# Check Multiple Boxes in Bootstrap/HTML

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How do I make it so checking one checkbox will check all the others in Bootstrap/HTML?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be great if you can provide us your code so that we can check what's wrong with it. What have you tried so far? Would you mind adding it into your post?

Answer (score 1):

It's irrelevant with Bootstrap. You need JavaScript to do it.

**Sample snippet:**

```js
function checkall(me) {
  const cbs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
  for (let i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    cbs.item(i).checked = me.checked
  }
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" onclick="checkall(this)">Check all</label>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```